# bootstraps CSS and JS files not working

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get bootstraps affixed side bar menu to work following the code used in this link. http://www.bootply.com/109952

I have the CSS and the JS in respective files, but when i load the web page, it looks a lot different, and none of the functionality works!!

Am i refernecing the files wrong in my HTML? Do i need to include some other ref, like the Jquery library? If so, how?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mainCSS/mainWEBcss.css' %}" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{% static 'mainJS/sideBarJS.js' %}"></script>
```

The rest of the code is the exact same from the web site i copied and pasted from, with the addition on the three lines pasted above. I know my load static files is fine though!

Posting my html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mainCSS/mainWEBcss.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{% static 'mainJS/sideBarJS.js' %}"></script>

</head>




<header class="navbar navbar-bright navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Bootply</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Get Started</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Visualize</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sec">Prototype</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id="masthead">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h1>Bootply
            <p class="lead">The easiest way to apply Bootstrap</p>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="well well-lg">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/180x100" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <strong>Important</strong>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah bla!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- /cont -->
</div>

<!-- Begin Body -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3" id="leftCol">

                <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#sec0">Section</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class=""><a href="#sec0a">- Sub 1</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sec0b">- Sub 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#sec1">Section 1</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                      <li class=""><a href="#sec1a">- Sub 1</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sec1b">- Sub 2</a></li>
                      <li class=""><a href="#sec1c">- Sub 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#sec2">Section 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sec3">Section 3</a></li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#sec4">Section 4</a>
                      <ul class="nav">
                          <li class=""><a href="#sec4a">- Sub 1</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h2 id="sec0">Content</h2>
                At Bootply we like to build simple Bootstrap templates that utilize the code Bootstap CSS without a lot of customization. Sure you can
                find a lot of Bootstrap themes and inspiration, but these templates tend to be heavy on customization.

                <hr>
                <div id="sec0a">
                   This is some mroe content Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae..
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div id="sec0b">
                   This is some mroe content Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae..
                </div>
                <br><br>


                <hr class="col-md-12">
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores
                eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores
                eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut!



                <h2 id="sec1">Content</h2>
                <p>
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Hello.</h3></div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
                      dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
                      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Hello.</h3></div>
                      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                      Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis
                      dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan.
                      Aliquam in felis sit amet augue.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="sec1a">
                  <h4>Section 1 a</h4>
                   This is some mroe content Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae..
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div id="sec1b">
                   <h4>Section 1 b</h4>
                   This is some mroe content Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae..
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div id="sec1c">
                   <h4>Section 1 c</h4>
                   This is some mroe content Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut.
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae..
                </div>
                <br><br>

                <hr>

                <h2 id="sec2">Section 2</h2>
                <p>
                Rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores
                eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut!
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="img-responsive"></div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <h2 id="sec3">Section 3</h2>
                Images are responsive sed @mdo but sum are more fun peratis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores
                eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut

                <h2 id="sec4">Section 4</h2>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores
                eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,
                sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut


                <hr>
              <h4><a href="http://bootply.com/75781">Edit on Bootply</a></h4>
                <hr>


            </div>
    </div>
</div>









    <p>This is the header file with bootstraps</p>
<!-- This is start of jinja -->
        {% include "loginpage/loginlogic.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

</html>
```

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: Seems like you're using Django. Can you check the browser console if the files are found or not? (404). Perhaps the location is wrong.

Comment: 06/Mar/2017 13:46:42] "GET /static/mainJS/sideBarJS.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[06/Mar/2017 13:46:42] "GET /static/mainCSS/mainWEBcss.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: Getting a 304, I am unfamiliar with that http response!

Comment: 304 = Not Modified - meaning it's a cached response

Comment: Ah ok, if you take a look at the code i reference in the link, is it not just a simple copy and paste? I am not too familiar with html/css/js

Comment: It might be worth posting your whole HTML page. If both the CSS and JS are getting loaded by the browser, then I'm guessing something is getting loaded in the wrong order.

Comment: Posted, i also added in the CDN ref just for testing, but it did not do anything!

Comment: try opening your browser console. F12 in  chrome would open it, then post the error log in red color.